Copyright on photographic reproductions of old paintings
If someone makes a photographic reproduction of a painting, and the painter died a hundred years ago, what rights does the photographer have?
Generally, making a photo of something is in itself a creative act and the photographer surely has copyright. But a photographic reproduction is more like a photocopy, even if it requires more skill.

"Generally, making a photo of something is in itself a creative act" NO! It CAN be a creative act. Just like moving a pen on paper can be a creative act (writing prose, painting etc.) and can also not be creative at all (doing calculations, your tax return etc.)

@Hobbamok The necessary creativity for a photo is very low, merely actively framing a subject is generally adequate. Thus, the vast majority of photographs contain creativity. The case here is somebody has put in great effort and skill to ensure the reproduction has no new creativity, that it reflects the painter's intent as closely as possible.

@user71659: It's unfortunate that the Supreme Court treats the notion of "writings and discoveries" as implying creativity, rather than recognizing that the sciences and useful arts might be better promoted by recognizing a short term "sweat of brow" exclusive right for non-creative works.  Someone who goes through painstaking effort to avoid introducing anything into a work that wasn't put there by the original artist should have a short term exclusive right to profit from their efforts, though anyone else who puts in comparable effort would effectively put any aspects of the work that...

...were shared by the two sweat-of-brow efforts into the public domain since it would be impossible to prove that any such aspect was copied from either work in particular.  Further, the way the Court treats the notion of creativity and photos effectively guarantees the creation of orphan works by "random strangers" who are asked to take photos.  Anyone who publishes a photo taken by a random stranger runs the risk that the stranger might be able to by some means prove that he was the one that took the photo, and demand retroactive royalties for its use.

@user71659 my only point was here to point out OPs fundamentally flawed approach of "if photo then copyight" because - as you said - it really depends on the details

european-union
germany
A faithful reproduction cannot be subject to copyright, if copyright of the original painting has expired.
Since this is an important topic for Wikipedia, the German-language Wikipedia covers copyright of images and photographs extensively in their guidelines:
Wikipedia: Bildrechte
They point out Directive (EU) 2019/790, which in Art. 14 says:

Member States shall provide that, when the term of protection of a
work of visual art has expired, any material resulting from an act of
reproduction of that work is not subject to copyright or related
rights, unless the material resulting from that act of reproduction is
original in the sense that it is the author's own intellectual
creation.

Wikipedia notes that this has been implemented in German law in 2021.

united-states
An exact photographic reproduction of a public domain painting lacks sufficient originality to gain copyright protection.
Bridgeman Art Library v. Corel Corp., 36 F. Supp. 2d 191 (S.D.N.Y. 1999)

So then a photo with some kind of treatment (say applying sepia tinting) could be protected (although anyone else would be free to come along and do exactly the same thing)? I guess I'm asking how 'exact' is this standard.

@SoronelHaetir Exactly where the line sits is ultimately up to the court, but in general, yes. If you've made any artistic choices or alterations to the work, that's protected authorship. Even if you haven't, if you curate a group of reproductions, you can get a copyright in the compilation. But in all cases you're getting copyright on the changes you've made and the result, not on the underlying work.

A very generic change such as sepia-toning or rendering an image in black and white might not be protected under the "scènes à faire" doctrine. Since black-and-white photography is a recognized convention, and that artistic choice is a necessary part of that convention, copyrighting that choice would effectively be saying "no one else gets to make this photo in black and white" which courts are reluctant to do.
